# Sum of infinite series defined recursively

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Suppose $s$, $t$, and $\delta$ are constants satisfying $0<s<t<1$ and $\delta>1$. An infinite sequence $\{y_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ defined as follows:

The initial term, $y_1$, is the positive root of $(1-s)y_1+sy_1^2=\delta$.

For $k\geq 1$,
$y_{k+1}$ is the positive root of $(1-s)y_{k+1}+sy_{k+1}^2=(1+t)y_k-ty_k^2$ given $y_k$.

I have trouble in calculating $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(y_k-1)$ although I can show that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}y_k=1$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your aim is to compute the sum of the series or to show that the series converges?

Comment: The usual method to obtain an equivalent at a better order is to reinject the value you found at the previous step and try to expand your function a bit more. Here, you can find a relationship between $y_{k+1}-1$ and $y_{k}-1$ which resembles a lot the one you have above, but with a constant. If (and that's a big if) I have not made mistake, I found $y_k-1\sim (\frac{1-t}{1+s})^k$.

Comment: As Matt suggested, I can redefine the sequence as $x_k=y_k-1$.

The initial term, $x_1$, is the positive root of $(1+s)x_1+sx_1^2=\delta-1$. 

For $k\geq 1$,
$x_{k+1}$ is the positive root of $(1+s)x_{k+1}+sx_{k+1}^2=(1-t)x_k-tx_k^2$ given $x_k$.

It is easy to see $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}x_k=0$. The question is how to calculate $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_k$.

Comment: To Did, I can show the series converges. If we add the first $N$ equations up and cancel out equal terms, we can get 
$\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}(s+t)y_k(y_k-1)=\delta-(1-s)y_N-sy_N^2$. 
Take limit of $N\rightarrow\infty$, as $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}y_N=1$, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}y_k(y_k-1)=(\delta-1)/(s+t)$. Since $y_k>1$, $y_k(y_k-1)>y_k-1$.
Therefore, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(y_k-1)$ exists. 
To Matt, thank you for your answer. How did you get $y_k-1\sim[(1-t)/(1+s)]^k$? If that is correct, how do you know that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(y_k-1)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}[(1-t)/(1+s)]^k$?

Comment: @Will This uses that $y_k\gt1$ for every $k$. Unfortunately this is not always so hence every subsequent argument fails. Actually in some cases the sequence $(y_k)$ is undefined:  if $\delta=16$, $s=1/3$ and $t=2/3$, then $y_1=6$, hence $y_2$ should solve $2y_2+y_2^2=-42$, which is impossible. What is happening?

Comment: Did, sorry that I forgot to say that constant $\delta$ is small enough that $(1+t)y_1-ty_1^1$ positive.